# API/Service that finds an optimal route for a given list of coordinates and start/end point

Tags: api, maps, google-maps

There is a source US address/coordinates **SOURCE** and a bunch of US addresses/coords **WAIPOINTS** that need to be visited. I want to get a list of **WAIPOINTS** sorted in a way that it creates a shortest circuit ending with the starting point **SOURCE** (or, if not possible, at least a shortest route to visit all the **WAIPOINTS** no matter where it ends.

It's a [Chinese postman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Route_inspection_problem) I think. I was checking Google Directions API but I didn't find such option.

Do you have any idea how to do that? Preferably a free option, I need to use it 10 times a month.